# WebDriver is NULL when start more then one test case

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testing, pageobjects

I have a problem. There are 2 Test classes in my code and when I run each 1 test case manually both working fine. But when execute tests with maven only one test is executed successfully and other gives me error

> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.selenium.course.tests.ProductTests.executeProductTest(ProductTests.java:17).

Expected behavior: all tests should execute with maven.

Here is my code = https://github.com/Dermenji/SeleniumCourse

Comment: show us what is in ProductTests.java: line number 17

Comment: 17.      ProductListerPage productListerPage = loginPage.login("standard_user", "secret_sauce");



Login Page -> login() method -> 
public ProductListerPage login(String usernameField, String passwordField){
        executeOperationWithExplicitWait(10, ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(username), 4);
        username.sendKeys(usernameField);
        password.sendKeys(passwordField);
        loginBtn.click();
        return new ProductListerPage(driver);
    }

Comment: are you running in parallel ?

Comment: yes, I run in parallel with test NG - suit

Answer (score 0):

In your base calass where you have get methods for the driver, you need a "global" class variable which will be static.

```
public static WebDriver driver;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is not a solution. Because when make it static I have execution of two classes at same time in same browser instances...

Answer (score 0):

Selenium also works with annotations which they have not yet implemented.

For me, many test cases caused errors after I added annotations everything went well.

https://www.browserstack.com/guide/testng-annotations-in-selenium

maybe this Site helps u.

Comment: Yes, I tried all test annotations... the problem is that class and method with page object pattern is not started...

Answer (score 0):

You should use same driver instance for all test classes

The solution is you can use util class for driver instance

Comment: Ping me i can share util class for driver instance

Comment: https://gist.github.com/JASJUSTIN/457aec1399dce751d1995903844537d6